# Is it possible to return data in $http.get().success() in a service factory()?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have create the contact list in angular js. In the below example i have created the service factory in that i was not able to handle the $http.post().success() method in the service.

```js
angular.module('contactApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/contactList', {
      templateUrl: 'template/contactList.cfm',
      controller: 'contList'
    }).
    when('/contactAddEdit', {
      templateUrl: 'template/contactAddEdit.cfm',
      controller: 'contactAddEdit'
    }).
    when('/contactAddEdit/:contactID', {
      templateUrl: 'template/contactAddEdit.cfm',
      controller: 'contactAddEdit'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/contactList'
    });
  }
])

.controller('contList', function($scope, studentSession) {

  studentSession.getSessions().success(function(data, status) {

    $scope.members = = queryToObject(data);

  });
})

.factory('studentSession', function($http) {

  return {

    getSessions: function() {

      return $http.get('template/dbSelect.cfm');

    }

  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `then()` and not `success()` you are returning the promise from the factory:

```
studentSession.getSessions().then(function(data, status) {

    $scope.members = = queryToObject(data);

  }).catch(function (err) {

    console.log(err);
  });
```

If you need a more support for old browsers like IE8 or android mobile < 4.1 use this instead:

```
studentSession.getSessions().then(function(data, status) {

        $scope.members = = queryToObject(data);

      },function (err) {

        console.log(err);
      });
```

**THEN** If you really want to return the promise success from the factory you'll need an event:

```
.controller('contList', function($scope, studentSession) {

  studentSession.getSessions();

  $scope.$on('session:retrievedSession', function (data) {

    console.log('Session retrieved is: ', data.response);
  });
})

.factory('studentSession', function($rootScope, $http) {

  return {

    getSessions: function() {

      return $http.get('template/dbSelect.cfm').success(function (response) {

        $rootScope.$broadcast('session:retrievedSession', {response:response});
      });

    }

  };
});
```

Comment: Note that this `.catch` will throw an error in IE8. You can use the second argument of `.then` to handle errors. Or if you really want to use `catch` you would have to write it as `["catch"]`.

Comment: @JonSnow ;) yep same for Android mobile < 4.1 afaik :)

Comment: Is it possible return the success() in factory?

Comment: or maybe i don't get what you need

Comment: @sbaaaang i was not able to capture the event $rootScope.$broadtcast(), you have injected the $rootscope in factory() but not injected the $broadtcast why?. thanks for spending your valuable time with me.

Comment: @Dineshkumar i have no time to test it, any error in console?

Comment: @Dineshkumar sorry my mistake is not $broadtcast() but its $broadcast() typo sorry, updated answer

Comment: @Dineshkumar try debugging a little bit :) try console.log(data); :)